# Select * from Table A but in Column 1 show what it matches up with in Table B

Tags: mysql

Apologies for the badly worded title but here is an example:

Table A

```
╔═══╦════════════╦═════════════╗
║   ║ title      ║ creator     ║
╠═══╬════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 1 ║ Lorem      ║ 1           ║
║ 2 ║ Ipsum      ║ 2           ║
║ 3 ║ Dolor      ║ 3           ║
╚═══╩════════════╩═════════════╝
```

Table B

```
╔═══╦════════════╦═════════════╗
║   ║ id         ║ name        ║
╠═══╬════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 1 ║ 1          ║ Tom         ║
║ 2 ║ 2          ║ John        ║
║ 3 ║ 3          ║ Harry       ║
╚═══╩════════════╩═════════════╝
```

Is it possible to have a query that will select all from Table A, but in the result it will link tableA.creator to tableB.name and show tableB.name in the result instead of tableA.creator?

Comment: Yes of course it is possible. You use the `join` operator to connect the tables. See this tutorial for an example: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT b.name FROM A a LEFT JOIN B b ON a.creator=b.id
```

Comment: Right, you know I was trying some joins but expecting the actual a.creator row to change to b.id, upon further inspection I can see now that it appends the rows from Table B onto the Table A results.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT A.Title, B.Name
FROM  TableA as A
INNER JOIN TableB AS B on(A.Creator = B.Id)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.title, b.name FROM A a LEFT JOIN B b ON a.creator=b.id
```

OR

```
SELECT a.title, b.name
FROM  A as a
JOIN B AS b on a.creator = b.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try as below query

```
select distinct A.title , B.name
from A join B
on A.creator = B.id
```